# Is it possible to fool a QSqlTableModel attached to a DB view when INSERTING/UPDATING

Tags: database, qt, postgresql

I have about 23 QSqlTableModel instances that are attached to PostGreSQL views.

I require the views from an application perspective to combine data from different database tables into a single Sql "Table" simply because it is easier than to create custom table models sourcing from the actual QSqlTableModel instances connected to the real database tables.

Some of these views feed into Tree Views, and I would like to be able to "Gracefully" update all the QT views attached to Models that are attached to PostGreSql database views.

A colleague suggested that I do an (insert into / update where) on the Models attached to the views, and then simply let the PostGreSql database views catch the command via a rule, and just do nothing with it.  I tried this, but the Qt Models don't "submit".  They don't retain the newly inserted/modified data.

Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: If INSERT/UPDATE worked in PostgreSQL side  but Qt model didn't get updated data adding RETURN NEW.* into trigger could help. If problem is on QT side i have no idea...

Comment: The DB view has rules for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.  The point is, the DB view should not do anything to the data (modifying the SQL tables that the view sources its data from will have done this already).  The problem is, I need to get the Sql Models attached to the db views in sync with the db views without calling select(); in the Sql models (it causes tree views to collapse, and this is undesired). For this reason I would rather attempt to INSERT or UPDATE the Qt Models, but I wish for this to not filter down to the database, or the database should simply ignore it.